# Returning to my app via URL in Ionic/AngularJS

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an app that works alongside another payment provider app and sends order data to it to process payment which is fine.

Having some problems getting the correct "url" to return to my app from the payment app.

For example, when testing this in a browser my url is

```
http://localhost:8100/#/tab/home
```

I assume in an app it is

```
com.ionicframework.creatorapp458965://#/tab/home
```

or perhaps

```
creatorapp://#/tab/home
```

Is the app path based on the name or widget id in config.xml in Ionic?

```
 widget id="com.ionicframework.creatorapp458965"
 <name>creatorapp</name>
```

Currently there is a http url in place with an order # appended that I want to send to an API somehow.

So looking at 1) The correct path of my app (eg. return the to the home page)
and
2)Returning to my app and sending/accessing

```
var returnUrl = "http://example.com/api/order/payment/" + ordernumber;
```

**EDIT- Custom-URL-scheme installed - Deeplink paths not workign yet**

Got my App opening from a webpage with (myschema://) but cannot deeplink as yet...I've tried

```
    myappschema:/#/tab/list
    myappschema://list
    myappschema:/#/tabs.list
    myappschema://list-tab
    myappschema://tabs.list

.state('tabs.list', {
  url: '/list',
  cache: false,
  views: {
    'list-tab' : {
     templateUrl: 'templates/list.html',
     controller: 'ListController'
    }
```

Comment: Look [Custom-URL plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme)

Comment: Got that installed now, its working to open up my app from, but struggling with the correct syntax to my list page. Please ee my above edit.